# Disable runtime permissions check for Android M root

Tags: android, root, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, galaxy-tab

Is there anyone who know how to disable danger permissions check for rooted android 6 or grant all of them automatically for my app?
I have rooted tablet Samsung sm-819 with android 6 and an application which used one set of permissions but now I must extend functionality of the application therefore app needs more permission.

The problem is that the app stuck to the screen and only shows ads in taxi cab. It's never interact with user and new permissions can't be granted...
Please help me to find any information about it. I know that it's possibly because different devices don't have the same set of dangerous permission.

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve this by setting targetSdk below 23.**

If you are using targetSdk 23 or above, then you need to implement the `runtime permission`.